# How to send out messages with a defined rate in ZeroMQ?

Tags: c, time, zeromq, measurement

I want to test how many subscribers I can connect to a publisher, which is sending out messages fast, but not with a maximum speed, e.g. every microsecond.

The reason is, if I send out messages with maximum speed, I miss messages at the receiver ( High-water-mark ).

I thought, I can use **`nanosleep()`**, and it works nice with 20 messages a second ( sleep: 50000000 [ns] ). But with a shorter sleeping time, it gets worse: 195 (5000000), 1700(500000), 16000 (50000) messages. And with even shorter sleeping times, I don't really get more messages. It seems that the sleep-function itself needs some time, I can see this, if I print out timestamps.

So, I think, it is the wrong way to run a function with a specific rate. But I didn't find a way to do that in another way.

Is there a possibility to send out roughly 1000000 messages a second?

Comment: See `man 7 socket`. Consider using `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF,...)` on receiver and `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,...)` on sender to increase the size of the _kernel_ socket buffers [so they have enough space to take the increased throughput]. Otherwise, receiver will [have to] drop incoming packets because receiver thread can't keep up with the burst rate. And sender will block waiting for space in the send buffer, so it will be limited on send rate (i.e. shorter sleep times don't help without this)

Comment: Would you mind to post which ZeroMQ API version does your Project aim to work with?

Comment: @CraigEstey: Thanks for your answer. I don't know, if I get it right, but I don't miss any message in the versions with nanosleep. Its really not sending out fast enough. 
When I'm only sending, without any sleep I can send out over 3,000,000 messages and can receive about 900,000 in a second. Thats the reason why I want to get around 1,000,000 messages per second. 
And it would be nice to try different rates, and see if that changes something in the number of possible subscribers.
Furthermore, don't I only shift the problem with increased buffers? Because sometime they will also be full.

Comment: ZeroMQ can ( and must ) manage also the buffer-mechanics, but let's start from one common point, not from the middle of the story. **What ZeroMQ API version do you aim to work with?** It is an important fact to start with, ok?

Comment: @user3666197: My current 0MQ version is 4.2.3
But I don't think it has much to do with ZeroMQ. It's more a C thing, because ZeroMQ does what I expect. Its sending as fast as possible, the latency goes up and then messages are dropped, like mentioned in the guide (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) in the section High Water Marks. 
So I'm fine with it, but want a C-application that is only calling the send function a specified number of times per second (It haven't to be exact, only roughly +- 1000 would be fine).

Comment: Oh yes it does, Sir. Thanks for the explicit statement. The initial and many "older" versions of the ZeroMQ were implemented with a **`SUB`**-side filtering of the subscriptions, whereas the newest API does this right on the **`PUB`**-side. Both alternatives having fatal implications on buffer-sizing ( the latter ) and the network-transport ( the former ) -- the more if going to run a performance test under controlled workloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Q: How to send out messages with a defined rate?

Given API is v.4.2.3+, one can use a **`{ pgm:// | epgm:// }`**-transport class for this very purpose and setup the adequately tuned **`.setsockopt( ZMQ_RATE, <kbps> )`** plus exhibit some additional performance related tweaking of buffer-sizing ( `ZMQ_SNDBUF`, `ZMQ_IMMEDIATE`, `ZMQ_AFFINITY`, `ZMQ_TOS` and `ZMQ_MULTICAST_MAXTPDU` ) with some priority-mapping e.t.c., so as to safely get as close to the hardware limits as needed.

---

### Q: Is there a possibility to send out roughly 1,000,000 messages a second?

Well, given not more than about a 1000 [ns] per a message-to-wire dispatch latency, a carefull engineering is due to take place.

The best candidate for such rate would be to use the **`inproc://`** transport class, as this does not rely on ZeroMQ's `Context`-instance IO-thread(s) performance / bottlenecks inside an external O/S scheduler ( and will definitely work faster than any other kind of available transport-classes ). Still, it depends, if it can meet less than the required 1000 [ns] latency, based on your application design and message sizes ( Zero-Copy being our friend here  to better meet the latency deadline ).

Comment: ( plus a minor note -- ZeroMQ ZMQ_SNDBUF sizes are not recommended to be tight-mapped to a theoretical amount of bytes, that are necessary to get buffered, a non-trivial alignment with the kernel-space SO_SNDBUF sizes being one known issue, plus more than about a double-space is experimentally shown to be helpful, due to message allocations / release to smoothly take place, without choking -- so setting just the O/S attributes is by far not enough to indeed help the ZeroMQ traffic flow smoothly on peak performance levels ). Do not hesitate to experiment.

Comment: Thanks, the answer to the first question is really interesting. I started to read about `{ pgm:// | epgm:// }`-transport class, and that is maybe a option, although it is a complete different solution I thougt of.